# Undefined function in React Router + Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Currently writing application in React + Redux stack. During development, I hit the problem where in one's of React component, Redux function work just fine and in index.js throwing that Redux function is undefined.

What I wish to do, is to keep user sign in between reloading of web page. So where pages reload, componentDidMonut function in index.js check if there is a token in localstorage then send one api call to check if JWT token did not expired. And if everthing is correct call redux function signIn() to rerender app.

In Login component login working and redirect to after sign in, unfortunately in index.js React throwing error:

[image: Error Screenshot].

After checking in console this function is simply undefined, and I don't know why.

Looking forward for pointing mistakes I made. Thanks in advance
Below code:

actions/index.js:

```
export const signIn = () => {
  return {
    type: "SIGN_IN"
  };
};

export const signOut = () => {
  return {
    type: "SIGN_OUT"
  };
};
```

reducers/authReducers:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  isSignedIn: null
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SIGN_IN":
      return { ...state, isSignedIn: true };
    case "SIGN_OUT":
      return { ...state, isSignedIn: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Login.js:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Container,
  Form,
  Grid,
  Header,
  Message,
  Segment
} from "semantic-ui-react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { signIn, signOut } from "../actions";
import api from "../api/api";

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isSignedIn: null,
      email: "",
      password: "",
      errorMessage: ""
    };
    this.errorMessageRef = React.createRef();
  }

  handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await api.login(this.state.email, this.state.password);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
        this.props.signIn();
        this.props.history.push("/flat");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      this.errorMessageRef.current.hidden = false;
      this.setState({ ...this.state, errorMessage: `${error}` });
      this.props.signOut();
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Grid centered columns={2}>
          <Grid.Column>
            <Header as="h2" textAlign="center">
              Login
            </Header>
            <Segment>
              <Form size="large">
                <Form.Input
                  fluid
                  icon="user"
                  iconPosition="left"
                  placeholder="Email address"
                  onChange={event =>
                    this.setState({ email: event.target.value })
                  }
                />
                <Form.Input
                  fluid
                  icon="lock"
                  iconPosition="left"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  type="password"
                  onChange={event =>
                    this.setState({ password: event.target.value })
                  }
                />
                <Button
                  color="blue"
                  fluid
                  size="large"
                  onClick={this.handleLogin}
                >
                  Login
                </Button>
              </Form>
            </Segment>
            <Message ref={this.errorMessageRef} negative={true} hidden={true}>
              Email or password and incorrect
            </Message>
            <Message>
              Not registered yet? <a href="/sign-up">Sign Up</a>
            </Message>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { signIn, signOut })(Login);
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { connect, Provider } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container } from "semantic-ui-react";
import reducers from "./reducers";
import { signIn, signOut } from "./actions";
import api from "./api/api";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import App from "./components/pages/App.js";
import Flat from "./components/pages/Flat";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import Duties from "./components/pages/Duties";
import MyDuties from "./components/pages/MyDuties";
import CreateFlat from "./components/flat/CreateFlat";
import JoinFlat from "./components/flat/JoinFlat";
import Payments from "./components/pages/Payments";
import "./components/index.css";

const store = createStore(reducers);

class Routing extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isSignedIn: null };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.isLoggedIn();
  }

  isLoggedIn = async () => {
    try {
      if (localStorage.getItem("token") != null) throw "user not sign in";

      await api.getCurrentFlatmate();
      this.props.signIn();
    } catch (e) {
      this.props.signOut();
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
          <Route path="/home" component={App} />
          <Route path="/sign-in" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/sign-out" component={App} />
          <Route path="/user" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/flat" component={Flat} />
          <Route path="/join-flat" component={JoinFlat} />
          <Route path="/create-flat" component={CreateFlat} />
          <Route path="/duties" component={Duties} />
          <Route path="/my-duties" component={MyDuties} />
          <Route path="/payments" component={Payments} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { signIn, signOut })(Routing);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Routing />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `this.props.dispatch(signOut())` instead of `this.props.signOut()`. 
And in the same way for `signIn()`